# how to get nested doc : collection("logs") -> doc("email.com")->collection("date") ->doc("time"))

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

i have "log (time)" doc inside collection ("date") inside other doc ("email") inside collection ("logs"), how i can pull single log object 
from this structure ?

the only way that its work for me is by hard-coded the full path for specific doc :

```
getLogs(email : string)
 {
    this.db.firestore.collection("logs")
   .doc(email)
   .collection("30-7-2019")
   .doc("10:29:41")
   .get()
   .then(res =>{console.log(res);});   
 }
```

The problem, of course, is that I can't provide a specific date and time, but only email, and when I try to access through "logs / some_email", its return empty array :

```
getLogs(email : string)
{
   this.db.firestore.collection("logs")
  .doc(email)
  .get()
  .then((res) => console.log(res));   
}
```

Any suggestions (: ?

Comment: Why can you not provide a specific date and time? I see there are hardcoded in your reference.

Comment: yes i give expmple for what work..

Comment: And what's wrong with it?

Comment: i dont want to hardcoded time and date

Comment: Do you want to use something like wildcards?

Comment: there are no wildcards in firestore

Comment: I know that, that's why I was asking you. In this case, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: the goal is to get each log object check some values

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't understand what you intend to do.

Comment: this is my db structure: collection("logs") that hold  doc(“email.com”)that hold emails or users  and inside of it i have collection of dates that hold  doc of time like :"21:30:11" and inside of this doc i have object of log

Comment: What about this reference?

Comment: What do you mean?